# How to get largest element from each row of n*n unsorted array?

Tags: algorithm

I have an unsorted array with n*n order. How to get the largest element from each row with complexity O(n logn).

Comment: You cannot do it if there is no knowledge at all on the array. The largest element in each row might happen to be the one you did not check, and you have no way to trim searches.

Answer (score 8):

You can not possibly do this. You have an input of size `O(n * n)` and each element of this input is a possible answer. You can not get better than `O(n * n)`.

Comment: if a single row is like [a b c d] then is it possible to find out each pair element of a row like (a,b)(a,c)(a,d) etc.. where a<b, a<c,a<d and so on with complexity O(log n).

Comment: @user3064366 what you describe is not logarithmic it is linear. If there is no known special property than you **have to** iterate through the whole array which is linear.